# How can I reduce the heat on these pipe soldering pliers?

Tags: microcontroller, power, current, heat

I'm trying to use these pipe soldering pliers https://www.garrettwade.com/copper-pipe-soldering-tool-gp.html to compress and heat the ends of nylon rope so that the ends are more finished and secure.

They currently heat up to around 900f. I need the heat to be around 400f. It would be really great if I could specify the temperature as you would with a good soldering iron, but I'm not sure how you'd do that.

The best idea I have is to reduce wattage with a simple in-line light switch or other similar dial.

Comment: You could try the dimmer switch idea. Make sure it's rated for the current/power. Realize you may destroy the dimmer switch and/or the pliers. Without a schematic of how they work, there's no way we can recommend a solution.

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be rated at 220W/125VAC, and if that's true you can easily use a dimmer-type device. Most of the ones designed for wall mounting are rated at 600W, but they're not very appropriate without a lot of work to make them enclosed, grounded and safe.

Most of the plug-in ones are two-wire (ungrounded) and/or rated for less than 220W so again inappropriate.

This particular one:

[image]

> Impact D1000 1,000W AC Dimmer Control (110-120V)

Is rated at 1kW, so plenty of power, and has a proper grounded plug and cord.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doubtful a dimmer would work. They're typically not rated for high current since the load they're working with is only a couple of amps (~250W) or so. I'm guessing your soldering tool is closer to 1000W.

On the other hand, a Variac can totally do this. Basically, Variacs are autotransformers that use a dial to set the turns ratio, and thus, the output AC voltage. They vary in cost depending on the load requirement.

With some experimentation you could arrive at a setting that gives the desired heat for fusing your rope ends.

Comment: Do you know what amperage range I should consider for a variac?

Comment: I was looking for that information for the soldering tool - it didn't show anything. 20A would work for sure.

Comment: the label on the tool says 220 W

Comment: So anything above 3A would work. That said there’s not much cost difference between a 10A and 20A variac, and  they have markings on the dial. For a production environment I’d want that to get repeatability.